# How can I measure the internal resistance of a thermoelectric generator?

Tags: dc, multimeter, thermal, peltier, internal-resistance

How can I measure the internal resistance of a thermoelectric generator? Can I use a standard multimeter? I am using a TEC1-12706B thermoelectric generator. I tried to use a standard multimeter to measure the internal resistance. Later I found that it is a positive component so that my measurement is wrong.

[image]

Comment: What value did you get for the internal resistance?  How did you try to measure it?

Comment: I connected a resistor to the thermoelectric generator and then measure the current through it, after that I used the formular R= U/I to calculated the internal resistor and found r= 517.8 Ohm

Answer (score 1):

> I connected a resistor to the thermoelectric generator and then measure the current through it, after that I used the formular R= U/I to calculated the internal resistor and found r= 517.8 ohm.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Flvn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Source resistance measuring circuit.*

- Stabilise the TEG temperature.
- Measure the open-circuit voltage output, \$ V_{OC} \$.
- Connect the load and measure the voltage under load, \$ V_L \$.
- Calculate the current, \$ I = \frac {V_L} {R_L} \$.
- Calculate the voltage drop across \$R_S\$, \$ V_d = V_{OC} - V_L \$.
- You now have the voltage drop across \$ R_S \$ and the current through it so you can calculate, \$ R_S = \frac {V_d} I \$.